# I want to create a new table from a SQL select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to be able to create new tables based on any SQL `select` statement. I have tried the following which I got the format from another question and it does not work (there are similar questions but not one that I found actually works). I keep getting an error on the SQL statement.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

This is the `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE MyNewTable
AS
 SELECT *
 FROM dbo.Bat
```

Comment: Generally, with [tag:SQL] questions, it's best to note which runtime you're aiming for -- MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.

Comment: On the top of the screen, here at work, it shows Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Which version of SQL is this one?

Comment: It would be [Microsoft SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server), which uses a flavor of SQL called [Transact-SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL).

Answer (score 4):

This will copy the entire table including rows

```
SELECT *
INTO newTableName
FROM dbo.Bat
```

Add `WHERE 1 = 0` to copy just the table structure

Answer (score 1):

If it is SQL Server (the dbo schema, default in SQL Server indicates it is SQL Server), you can do following.

```
select * into MyNewTable from dbo.Bat;
```

The SELECT INTO statement does not copy your table constraints. 
You statement is a valid Oracle and MySQL statement though.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT is simple (by deliberately ignoring for example the concepts of storage)

To create a table with all its lines
code:

```
CREATE TABLE XX AS SELECT * FROM YY ;
```

the result of command in mysql
[image]